# scanning a delimited file and validating it using functions

Tags: java, validation

I have a delimited file, which needs to be validated using a mapping document.

Example:

Main file

```
Anchit|80808080|AECS layout|26-JUL-2015
@neja|80A8000|AECS layout|26-JUL-2015
```

Mapping file

```
1=ALPHA
2=NUMERIC
```

here 1 is first column for main file, 2 is second column and so on

ALPHA pattern should be regex validation function which I have in my routine
NUMERIC pattern should be regex validation function which I have in my routine

Need to understand Java code to validate main file data using mapping file validation patterns and column numbers.

Main file columns can vary from 5 to 50 and so for mapping file rows.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: trying to create a file validation automation in Talend using java. Tried scanning both the files, but how will we check columns of main file based on numbering in mapping file and about its validation patterns.

Comment: Please show your current implementation.

Comment: Scanning  both files implementation is:

Comment: Scanner read = new Scanner (new File(((String)globalMap.get("tCreateTemporaryFile_1_FILEPATH"))));
read.useDelimiter(context.delimiter);
String Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4;

while (read.hasNext())
{
   Column1 = read.nextLine();
   Column2 = read.nextLine();
   Column3 = read.nextLine();
   Column4 = read.nextLine();
   System.out.println(Column1 + " " + Column2 + " " + Column3 + " " +
                      Column4 + "\n"); // just for debugging
}
read.close();

Comment: /*BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(context.mapping_file));
    String line1 = null;

    while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null)
     {
      String[] values = line1.split("=");
      for (String str1 : values) 
      {
        System.out.println(str1);
      }
    }
    br.close();    */

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is probably too late to help this user, but in case it can help someone else, you may want to look at the [CSV-Schema](https://github.com/digital-preservation/csv-schema) and [CSV-Validator](https://github.com/digital-preservation/csv-validator) projects that are provided by the UK National Archives.

These projects would require some alterations to the mapping file you specified above but I would think it would be sufficient to meet your validation needs in Java or Scala.